# How does backtracking differ from back-referencing in regular expressions?

Tags: ruby, regex

1. ***How does backtracking differ from back-referencing in regular expressions?***
2. ***How does back-referencing win limitation having with backtracking or vice-versa?***

Comment: 1. Define backtracking. 2. Define back referencing. 3. `???`

Comment: These are very different concepts. Did you try looking up their definitions?

Comment: Yes, I did the and got the concept of `backtracking`.But confused with `back-referencing` concept. As a newbie to this confused to understand how the two concept works and produces match!So any tiny code with two concepts to show how they differs would be helpful to understand the whole logic!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Backtracking is a way for a state machine to back up and retry other matches for a regular expression. It's something that's pretty much *internal* to the regex engine.

For example, say you're trying to match the regex `[a-z]*a`, any number of lower case characters followed by an `a`.

Given the input `abca`, a greedy match will assign all of that to the `[a-z]` portion of the regex but then there's no way to match the final `a`. Backtracking allows the engine to back up by returning that final `a` to the input stream and trying again, assigning `abc` to the `[a-z]` portion and `a` to the `a` portion.

---

Back-referencing on the other hand, is a means for a *user* of the regex engine to reference previously captured groups. For example,

```
s/^([a-z])([a-z])/\1_\2/
  \_____/\_____/
     |      |
     |      +- capture group 2
     +-------- capture group 1
```

may be a command to insert `_` between two consecutive lower case letters at the start of each line. The `\N` back-reference (where `N` represents a number) refers back to the groups captured within `()`.

Comment: Isn’t back-referencing rather referencing a previously matched string inside the pattern itself, e.g. `([a-z])\1`?

Comment: Whether back-references are allowed in both search and replacement sections depends on the regex engine itself (some of the older ones didn't even allow back-refs at all). In any case, the concept remains the same, it's a way to refer back to a previously captured group.

Comment: @paxdiablo `+1` to you!Both the concept is now 100% clear to me.Just asking does my second question is really valid? Is there situation where `backtracking` failed,and `back-referencing` wins over it or vice-versa?

Comment: @TheMiddleMan, sorry, I can't really make sense of it - they're really different things, to the point where they're not really interchangeable. It may be that I've just misunderstood that part of the question.

Comment: Anyway thank you very much again:) You have given a mind blowing explanation!